# Customizing the dash-daq gauge's knob

Tags: python, css, plotly-dash, plotly-python

I'm trying to fully customize a [dash-daq gauge](https://dash.plotly.com/dash-daq/gauge) appearance. First I wanted to remove the needle which I succeeded by adding to my gauge a class (*no-needle*) and setting in the CSS the following style:

```
.no-needle line {
   stroke: none !important;
}
```

I found this CSS property by [exploring through the browser inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mVJUO.png), and it worked, as you can see in the following [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7pH1v.png)

Then I wanted to remove the central "knob", but didn't find a way to do it. I'm struggling because the knob is not a single element like the needle (which was a *line*), as you can see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SP2C7.png). I tried to explorer in the dash-daq documentation but didn't find any option to alter the style of the needle and/or the central knob.

Is it even possible ?

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you for your time.

(versions I'm using)
`dash==1.0.1`
`dash-daq==0.1.5`

Comment: Strange I can't reproduce this. The knob renders for me as a `circle` element which can be easily hidden by targeting `.needle-knob`.

Comment: @BasvanderLinden Thank you very much for your answer. I didn't pay enough attention but I also have this `.needle-knob` class (screenshot [here](https://i.imgur.com/WQG2s6L.png)). So I just created a CSS rule to hide it. (I don't know why but just `.needle-knob { display: none; }` isn't enough to make it disappear, so I had to create the following rule : `.no-needle use { display: none; }` (I specified `no-needle` because I have multiple gauge and I want only for this one to be hidden). I don't if there is a better way to do it, but it works so, won't complain. Ty !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found* a (dirty?) solution to do it by creating the following CSS rule:

```
.no-needle use {
    display: none;
}
```

(I’m specifying the .no-needle here because I have many gauges on my page and I want to hide only one).

*Thank’s to [Bas van der Linden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68908692/customizing-the-dash-daq-gauges-knob?noredirect=1#comment121789556_68908692)